# Plotly Graph Object Size not chanding with 'renderer' keyword in fig.show()

Tags: plotly, plotly.graph-objects

when I try to use the `renderer = 'svg'` in plotly `fig.show()`, I am not able to change the size of the figure, when using the below command.

```
fig = go.Figure(data = [
        go.Pie(values = target_distribution, labels = labels, textinfo = 'label+percent+value' , pull = [0,0.04])], 
         layout = go.Layout(title = 'Distribution of Target Variable', width = 800))
fig.show(renderer = 'svg')
```

If I remove the renderer argument, the size can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Ploting with static renderer (png, svg etc), figure height, width wont reflect in result plot. As you are using svg renderer, it will use default settings to plot.

Plotly static renders comes with some default values and yes those can be changed.
To check options for specific renderer, in your case it's "svg"

```
import plotly.io as pio
svg_renderer = pio.renderers["svg"]
print(svg_renderer)
```

you will see some options as width, height, etc..

You can change defaults:

```
svg_renderer.width = 800
svg_renderer.height = 500
svg_renderer.engine = 'kaleido' #static image generation dependency, install it using pip or conda.

pio.renderers.default = "svg"  # set as default renderer (optional)
```

Plot based on renderer changes:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3])],
    layout_title_text="A Figure Displayed with the 'svg' Renderer"
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

For more details, please check plotly docs- [static plots](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/#static-image-renderers)